# What is the difference between "is" and "==" in python?

Tags: python, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python ‘==’ vs ‘is’ comparing strings, ‘is’ fails sometimes, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Is

```
a == b
```

the same as

```
a is b
```

?

If not, what is the difference?

Edit:
Why does

```
a = 1
a is 1
```

return True, but

```
a = 100.5
a is 100.5
```

return False?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why/1504742#1504742 among many others

Comment: Oops, sorry. That one didn't show up in the list when I asked this--feel free to close this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, these aren't the same. `is` is a check for object identity - ie, checking if `a` and `b` are exactly the same object. Example:

```
a = 100.5
a is 100.5  # => False
a == 100.5  # => True

a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
a == b  # => True
a is b  # => False
a = b
a == b  # => True
a is b  # => True, because if we change a, b changes too.
```

So: use `==` if you mean the objects should represent the same thing (most common usage) and `is` if you mean the objects should be in identical pieces of memory (you'd know if you needed the latter).

Also, you can overload `==` via the `__eq__` operator, but you can't overload `is`.

Comment: Java doesn't have `is`, so it's hard to say how this is the exact opposite of it.

Comment: in java, `==` tests memory address

Comment: good answer, but doesn't answer the part about `a is 1` returning true.

Comment: yep, that was an edit after the fact. this is interpreter-dependent, and reflects the fact that small integers are cached for speed. thus things equal to `1` will point to the same address for performance reasons. you can't rely on this, though.

Comment: @hasen j I'm not sure about the underlying engine, but if `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = [1,2,3]`, then wouldn't `a == b` evaluate to true regardless of memory address?

Comment: @Jeremy, in Java `a = [1,2,3]` is not valid code

Comment: @hasen j I was focusing more on the `==` operator; you could use `a=1; b=1` for syntactical correctness.  I think I am simply misinterpreting your comment though.

Answer (score 5):

As already very clearly explained above.

> **is** : used for identity testing (identical 'objects')
>
> **==** : used for equality testing (~~ identical value)

Also keep in mind that Python uses string interning (as an optimisation) so you can get the following strange side-effects:

```
>>> a = "test"
>>> b = "test"
>>> a is b
True
>>> "test_string" is "test" + "_" + "string"
True

>>> a = 5; b = 6; c = 5; d = a
>>> d is a
True  # --> expected
>>> b is a
False # --> expected
>>> c is a
True  # --> unexpected
```

Comment: For numbers, it only works for integers that take on byte (e.g. `<= 256`)

Comment: And for strings, it doesn't "detect" similar strings magically. Consider: `>>> a = "test"
>>> b = "test"
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = "test_string"
>>> c = b + "_string"
>>> a == c
True
>>> a is c
False
`

Comment: this is due to the length of the strings / integers, and is **interpreter dependent**: don't rely on this behaviour.